# Convert Google Scholar alert into RSS feed

Tags: rss, google-alerts, google-scholar

I have created a Google Scholar email alert and I'm trying to figure out how to turn that into an RSS feed. Google Scholar alerts has no RSS feed option, unfortunately. Below is a picture of what the alert looks like in email. I'm trying to use Gmail filters in combination with a service like ifttt.com to automatically turn alert emails into RSS. THe question: how to turn a recurring Google Scholar alert email into an RSS feed.

[image]

Comment: Is IFTTT not working for you? You should be able to create a recipe with email from Google Scholar Alerts as the trigger and RSS feed as the response.

Comment: It appears that IFTTT doesn't allow RSS as an action, only as a trigger. So it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

Steps necessary:

1. Create a **throwaway special purpose e-mail account** on the Web, with a username/password pair different from whatever you use elsewhere. (THIS IS IMPORTANT to minimize damage in case of security breach).
2. Register at [Emails2RSS](http://emails2rss.appspot.com/).
3. Step 2 gives you another e-mail address @emails2rss.appspot.com.
4. In your special purpose account, set up forwarding rule to the address obtained in Step 3.
5. Get the address of the RSS feed in the Emails2RSS application.
6. Enjoy!

Caveats:

1. I lack personal, hands-on experience with Emails2RSS. (I prefer pure RSS for the time being, but may experiment with e-mail stuff later).
2. E-mail notifications shouldn't exceed 750 kB.
3. The RSS feed has no security built in. You have to make sure the link isn't available to others (if you use the resulting RSS feeds on your web site and the addresses are stored in the source, it may be advisable to use Yahoo Pipes! or IFTTT as another layer of indirection, caching and DoS protection).